# how to get sql server service information using tsql

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1, we have a new dmv - `sys.dm_server_services` which is great for grabbing SQL Server services related info easily.

Is there any similar sys view/catalog or a tsql hack that I can query easily for earlier version of SQL Server, like SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CLR or PowerShell, perhaps, but not likely from straight T-SQL. The DMV you're talking about pulls this information from the SQL Server process in a way that you can't `(TABLE DM_SERVER_SERVICES)`, not from some system table that you have programmatic access to...

From PowerShell you can use things like [`Get-Process`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855) or [`Get-Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176858.aspx) for some of this information (and filter on the current instance name or `MSSQLSERVER` if it's a default instance). With C# you could [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842533/in-c-sharp-how-do-i-query-the-list-of-running-services-on-a-windows-server) but I don't know of any ready-made code for SQLCLR.

Comment: And I hesitate to suggest it, but maybe even `xp_cmdshell` could be used here to call `tasklist` or `wmic process get` (though the default output on the latter is horrible).

Comment: Example: `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'wmic service where "Name like ''%sql%''" get';`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. xp_cmdshell is blocked on the server. PS seems to be the way to go. strangely, when I connected to the remote sql server. The get-service returns all things on my local workstation

Comment: You need to run PowerShell commands against the remote server. Or explain what you mean by "connected to the remote sql server" and where exactly you ran get-service from in that case.

Comment: due to our network configuration. I can not launch PS within SSMS to specific remote sql server (return network-related error) but I was able to do following: >cmd >sqlps > cd sql\remoteserver >PS SQLSERVER:\sql\remoteserver> Get-Service and it returns all services running on my local workstation.

Comment: @Joy right, because that's not a SQL Server command, that's a Windows command. So your UI is going to pass that to your local operating system even though you've run the command from within a sqlps prompt. If you want it to run on a different computer you need to tell it so, e.g. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName remoteComputerName {Get-Service}`

Comment: Ah...I was too new to PS. THANK YOU for the hint! I got it work as: > Get-Service -ComputerName remoteserver

Comment: Ah see when I learned PowerShell a lot of these cmdlets didn't have their own -ComputerName parameter, glad to see that's changed.