# How to login remotely and get the services list

Tags: c#

I'm able to get the services (services.msc) for my computer. But i want the list of services to be displayed from other computer (should remotely login).

NOTE: I don't want the services.msc list for the remote machine's. I want a particular services (console application (.msc)) which is placed on the desktop.

Can anyone please help me achieving this? I'm trying since 4days but couldn't able to get it. Below is my code where i have used to fetch the services from my own computer:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceController[] se = ServiceController.GetDevices();
        ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

        int i = 0;

        foreach (ServiceController service in services)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["dgvcServiceName"].Value = Convert.ToString(service.ServiceName);
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["dgvcStatus"].Value = Convert.ToString(service.Status);
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["dgvcDescription"].Value = Convert.ToString(service.DisplayName);
            i += 1;  
        }
```

Please suggest me the way to get it. Thanks again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842533/in-c-sharp-how-do-i-query-the-list-of-running-services-on-a-windows-server look at this post. may solve your problem

Comment: I have added the code in the link shared above under button_click event (where that button is for connecting to the remote machine).

Comment: adding remote machine name worked ?

Comment: I have to check as the code is in different location.

Comment: I would like to know whether the code i have written will fetch the services from the services which is placed in remote machine's desktop?

Comment: When i deploy it in remote machine and checked, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

use System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServices("MachineName")
to get the list of services on a remote system.

what you are doing is ServiceController.GetServices().
which will get the services from the local system.

Comment: sorry, the i dont have admin previlages in my macine to try.